# IE doesn't call server side action when you press back

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, sammy.js

So I have a issue with I have two steps: Step 1 and Step 2. I am able to go to Step 2 but when I press back Step 1 does get loaded but doesn't make a call to the server. This issue is only present in IE. Currently I am using IE10, but in compatibility mode the same issue is duplicated.

I have attached a example project. If you place a breakpoint in the "GetStep1" action in HomeController. You will see that the breakpoint doesn't get caught when press back in IE10. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Download example here:
http://sdrv.ms/19mrZL7

### _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/sammy-0.7.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
            </div>
            <div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

### Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<ul>
    <li id="Step-1">
        <a href="#Step1">Step1</a>
    </li>

    <li id="Step-2">
        <a href="#Step2">Step2</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="dynamicData">
</div>
@section scripts{


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var IndexViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            self.selectedStep = ko.observable();

            Sammy(function () {
                this.get('#Step1', function () {
                    console.log('here');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/GetStep1',
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#dynamicData').html(result);
                            self.selectedStep(1);
                        }
                    });
                });

                this.get('#Step2', function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/GetStep2',
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#dynamicData').html(result);
                            self.selectedStep(2);
                        }
                    });
                });

                this.notFound = function () {
                    //console.log(location.hash);
                };

            }).run('#Step1');
        };


        ko.applyBindings(new IndexViewModel());
    </script>
}
```

_Step1.cshtml

```
<h1>Step 1</h1>
<div id="step1-view">
    <h1 data-bind="text: SelectedValue"></h1>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Collection">
        <li data-bind="css: {'selected' : $data === $root.SelectedValue()}, click: $root.setValue"><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
    </ul>
    @*<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></span>*@
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
    viewModel.setValue = function (item) {
        viewModel.SelectedValue(item);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("step1-view"));
</script>
```

### HomeController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetStep1()
        {
            return PartialView("_Step1", new Step1ViewModel());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetStep2()
        {
            return PartialView("_Step2", new Step2ViewModel());
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean in compatibility mode?

Comment: Press F12 in the browser to bring up developer's tool. On the toolbar in the developer's tool. There is "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode". I have tried running this example in IE8, and its happening over there too.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't crash on console.log? Try to comment it out.

Comment: yeah! the console.log was just placed in just test to see the sammy was being called, and it does display in the console. Its doesn't work even with that not there.

Comment: Throwing another idea here: could you have caching issue? Try clearing the browser cache before hitting back.

Comment: i think the caching issue with the sammy.js framework. Something is not letting it hit server action when it comes to IE. Chrome and FireFox work great! I have clear the cache many times and it just doesn't work. I have attached the code with example, you can try to see if it happen for you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to all of the Actions fixes the issue:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```